# How to use classes from other packages in SmartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

If I try use method from another package, I'm getting an error:

> [ERROR] [odminterface] - Errors in
>   'file:/C:/Eclipse%20EE%20WS/ODMInterface/src/com/odminterface/client/ODMInterface.java'
>
> [ERROR] [odminterface] - Line 71: No source code is available for type
>   com.testpack.test.PackTest; did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?
>
> [ERROR] [odminterface] - Unable to find type
>   'com.odminterface.client.ODMInterface'
>
> [ERROR] [odminterface] - Failed to load module 'odminterface' from
>   user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/10.0.2' at 127.0.0.1:6575

My project:
http://s019.radikal.ru/i616/1207/2e/1e224907c5c1t.jpg

ODMInterface.gwt.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='odminterface'>

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name='com.smartgwt.SmartGwt'/>

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean'/>

<entry-point class='com.odminterface.client.ODMInterface'/>

<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>
</module>
```

PackTest code:

```
package com.testpack.test;


public class PackTest 
{

public void test()
{

}
}
```

If I put "PackTest" class to "com.odminterface.client" pakage - all work fine.

How to call a class method that is in another package?

Comment: You should read this first : https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideOrganizingProjects?hl=fr
Your image is way too small to be visible

Answer (score 1):

By default GWT looks for java sources in `client` package relative to the package of module (e.g. module is in `ODMInterface.gwt.xml` is in package `com.odminterface` so java sources will be expected to be in 'com.odminterface.client').

Additional packages can be added using `source` tag  (see your `ODMInterface.gwt.xml` for example usage, there are already two packages added using `source` tag).